# Does Trace32 support linux 4.x awareness?

Tags: trace32

I'm using linux kernel 4.9 and Trace32 debugger.

I want to use linux-awareness debug mod, but Trace32 client has only linux-awareness for 2.x and 3.x.

Could I use linux-awareness 4.x?

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux-3.x kernel awareness from Lauterbach works also for Linux-4.x